# How to forward local server on XXXX port to sever outside firewall on port XXXX

Tags: ssh, http, web-development

Using
ssh -R 9333:localhost:9333 remotehost.com

I'd like to be able to navigate to this via Chrome/Firefox/IE without have to use socks.

http://domain.com:9333

Comment: I think you have your forwarding backwards. Which host is your server running on?

Comment: The dev-server is running locally on my machine. I'd like to push it to a foreign machine that is not behind a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After "-R 9333:localhost:9333" your 9333 port forwards to 9333 of the lo0 of the remotehost. (lo0 is usally the localhost). So if you application listens 9333 on lo0, you can navigate it by simply typing on the ssh client side:

```
http://localhost:9333
```

Comment: How can I use eth0 rather the lo0?

Comment: "ssh -R 9333:remotehost.com:9333 remotehost.com". But you should check the name resolution of the 'remotehost.com' on the remotehost side: `# host remotehost.com`. You should also be sure than your application listens needed port: `# netstat -na | grep :9333`

Comment: tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9333          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:9333                :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: I guess now I need to figure out how to access it from: domain.com:9333. Any thoughts?

Comment: If I got you right you should use -L instead or -R: `ssh -L 9333:localhost:9333 remotehost.com` and then navigate to `http://localhost:9333` on the client side

Comment: Other way around, I want to expose my local to my remote. Think port forwarding.

Comment: With `ssh -R 9333:localhost:9333 remotehost.com` you forward local 9333 to remote 9333. So if your local app is binded to localhost:9333 on the client side it can receive requests from remotehost.com. `ssh -L 9333:localhost:9333 remotehost.com` allows you to navigate localhost:9333 on the client side and get access to app which is binded to localhost:9333 on the remotehost

Comment: ssh -R 9333:remotehost.com:9333 ssh -g -L 9334:127.0.0.1:9333 -- 'g' allows me to bind to all interfaces and it does not work for -R. This is apparently by design and the manual is not updated. I can access it on domain.com:9334

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6984/discussion-between-dchirikov-and-jbcurtin)

Comment: Finally I catch what you want: enable Gateway ports ("GatewayPorts yes") in /etc/ssh/sshd_config, restart sshd and connect to 'ssh -R 9333:remotehost.com:9333 remotehost.com'